# how to install two separate phpmyadmin in one server via virtualhost

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm not asking about two mysqlhost in one phpmyadmin, this is my current configuration.
But I'd like to change it to two seperate phpmyadmin, so I can open two url in two tabs like:

xxx.com:8001

xxx.com:8002

at the same time (without session or token error when accessing at the same time)
they should link to different mysqlhost.

I'v tried copy two phpmyadmin folders (blowfish_secret changed) and using virtualhost port to link them.

But still got the same token error. Anything I miss?

Thanks!

This is my virtualhost config：

```
 20 NameVirtualHost *:8005
 21 NameVirtualHost *:8006
 28 <VirtualHost *:8005>
 29     DocumentRoot "/home/users/xx/phpmyadmin"
 30     ErrorLog "logs/phpmyadmin-error_log"
 31 </VirtualHost>
 32 
 33 
 34 <VirtualHost *:8006>
 35     DocumentRoot "/home/users/xx/phpmyadmin2"
 36     ErrorLog "logs/phpmyadmin2-error_log"
 37 </VirtualHost>
 38 
 39
```

and my phpadmin config:

```
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xx'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */
 20 
 21 $cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 3600;
 25 $i = 0;
 26 
 30 $i++;
 31 /* Authentication type */
 32 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'xx';
 33 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
 34 /* Server parameters */
 35 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'xx';
 36 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
 37 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
 38 /* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
 39 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
 40 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

all the same except the blow_secret.

Thanks

Comment: you need to give more information about this, your virtualhost configuration, what error do you get, etc.

Comment: would `xxx.com/phpmyadmin1` and `xxx.com/phpmyadmin2` be a problem?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that open two browser ( like chrome and safari ) for the two different phpmyadmin will do the trick.

The reason causes this may be the server auth_type is the cookies for both the site. So, any tabs in one browser will share the same cookie for their host is the same.